# Dockerfile: skip passphrase for private key

Tags: github, docker, dockerfile, ssh-keys

I'm using private keys for downloading my repository from Github in my Docker file. I have something like this:

```
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && echo "$MY_PRIVATE_KEY" >/root/.ssh/id_rsa &&    chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa &&    ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts &&    cat /root/.ssh/known_hosts &&    ssh -vvv git@github.com &&    pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/my_project.git@v1.0.0 &&    rm /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Where `MY_PRIVATE_KEY` is an argument. I'm not able to re-create this key.
My issue is that during connection process I'm getting the following error:
`key_load_private_type: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key`

Is it possible to skip passphrase somehow?

Answer (score 6):

The passphrase is required to decrypt the key.  You can't "skip" it.  You could *remove* the passphrase on the key using `ssh-keygen -p` (see the man page for details).

You may want to investigate the use of a [GitHub Deploy Key](https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys), which is a per-repository ssh key that grants read-only access to the repository.  These are meant to solve *exactly* the situation you find yourself in: needing to automaticaly deploy software from a GitHub repository that requires authentication.

Comment: Yes, use Github Deploy Keys instead. That's a best practice for interacting with Github in a non dev environment.

Comment: As I mentioned above I'm not able to re-generate the key

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you re-generate the key.  I was suggesting that you either (a) remove the password from the key, or (b) use an additional key. I apologize if that wasn't clear from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MY_PRIVATE_KEY` seems to be passphrase-protected (a key with an empty passphrase is **not** the same as a non-encrypted key).

The key in `.ssh/id_rsa` is normally not passphrase-protected, instead it is protected by permissions to allow only owner access (0600).

You can remove the passphrase from your key using OpenSSL like this:

```
set MY_PRIVATE_KEY = `echo $MY_PRIVATE_KEY | openssl rsa`
```

The contents of `id_rsa` should look like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
. . .
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and it turns out the reason is **the ssh key was copied differently due to the Makefile**